# remove part of a url using regex

Tags: python

This is the url:

```
url = "www.face.com/me/4000517004580.html?gps-id=5547572&scm=1007.19201.130907.0&scm_id=1007.19201.130907.0&scm-url=1007.19201.130907.0&pvid=56aacc48-cc78-4cb9-b176-c9acb7a0662c"
```

I need to remove the part after the **.html**, so it becomes:

```
"www.face.com/me/4000517004580.html"
```

Comment: How are you distinguishing where to cut the string off? As far as I can see you could just use `url.split('?')[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
url.split('.html')[0]+'.html'
```

result:

```
'www.face.com/me/4000517004580.html'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to parse the url into parts and then remove the query string from the url

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = "www.face.com/me/4000517004580.html?gps-id=5547572&scm=1007.19201.130907.0&scm_id=1007.19201.130907.0&scm-url=1007.19201.130907.0&pvid=56aacc48-cc78-4cb9-b176-c9acb7a0662c"

parse_result = urlparse(url)
url = parse_result._replace(query="").geturl()  # Remove query from url
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are not sure how to approach a problem, I suggest starting with some documentation. For example, you can check out the [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) and [common string operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).

Scrolling through this list, you will read about the `find()` function:

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found within the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if sub is not found.

So to find the `"?"` you can do this:

```
i = url.find("?")
```

Rather than thinking about how to remove part of the string, let's figure out how to **keep** the part we want. We can do this with a slice:

```
url = url[:i]
```

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `urllib` library can be used here.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse

url = 'www.face.com/me/4000517004580.html?gps-id=5547572&scm=1007.19201.130907.0&scm_id=1007.19201.130907.0&scm-url=1007.19201.130907.0&pvid=56aacc48-cc78-4cb9-b176-c9acb7a0662c' 
output = urljoin(url, urlparse(url).path)
```